# Slow convergence of Fresnel integral evaluation

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

I am trying to solve a problem from optics, a so-called Fresnel integral. The argument of integration is defined with a function:

```
AmplitudeArgument[\[Xi] : {x1_, y1_, z1_}, \[Xi]0 : {x0_, y0_, 
     z0_}, \[Lambda]_] := Block[{r},
   r = Sqrt[(x1 - x0)^2 + (y1 - y0)^2 + (z1 - z0)^2];
   Exp[r/2] Exp[I 2 \[Pi]/\[Lambda] r]/r (1 + z1/r)
   ];
```

I evaluate the argument into a variable, so that I obtain an expression with only a few parameters left unspecified (this should make quadrature efficient):

```
f1d = AmplitudeArgument[{x, 1. 10^-6, 1. 10^-6}, {x0, y0, 0.}, \[Lambda]];
f2d = AmplitudeArgument[{x, 1. 10^-6, z}, {x0, y0, 0.}, \[Lambda]];
f3d = AmplitudeArgument[{x, y, z}, {x0, y0, 0}, \[Lambda]];
```

I also formed a Region for integration, but ended up not using it in my explorations since I am still debugging:

```
\[ScriptCapitalR] = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 <= 10^-6, {x, y}];
```

Ultra slow conversion is challenging me, for example with the following Plot command:

```
Plot[Exp[-\[Alpha] ] Re[
   1/(2 I \[Lambda])
     NIntegrate[f1d, {x0, y0} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], 
     WorkingPrecision -> 1]], {x, 0, 2 10^-6}]
```

To speed things up, I generate a table of coordinates, and then evaluate the integral for each coordinate, viz:

```
Monitor[ListPlot[
  Table[Exp[-\[Alpha] ] Re[
     1/(2 I \[Lambda])
       NIntegrate[N[f1d], {x0, y0} \[Element] \[ScriptCapitalR], 
       WorkingPrecision -> 1, MinRecursion -> 5, 
       AccuracyGoal -> 5]], {x, \[Delta]/4, l, \[Delta]/4}], 
  Joined -> True], x/max1d]
```

This at least lets me see that the problem is correctly defined. I get this from ListPlot, which is expected:

[image: ListPlot result of evaluating the integral at points along a line.]

The plot has strange jumps, due to nonconvergence of the numerical integration. What I really want is to produce 2D slices of the final result. Infinite patience for a 2D region produced:

[image: Very rough plot of a 2D region.]

which is not satisfactory. Any advice on how to handle the integration (special quadrature, tricks with the integration settings for better control over convergence, etc) would be most appreciated.

Many thanks in advance,

Jan

Comment: Have you tried converting to polar coordinates?

Comment: What's the value of `\[Lambda]`?

Comment: Good point, sorry. I took it at 350 nm, since this is a UV lithography problem.

Comment: I did not try polar coordinates (yet). On the other hand, since the cartesian coordinates are immediately converted to a radius, which is polar, I can't imagine that the problem will go away. Unless you have an idea why this would be a good option.

Comment: Converting to polar form is usually one of the first things to try if an integral in Cartesian form has radial symmetry, and is difficult to compute in that format.